# Changing the prototype of the String object

Tags: javascript, strings

Are there any pitfalls in changing the prototype of the `String` object? I'd like to change the word `substr` to "left":

```
String.prototype.left = function(n) {
    return this.substr(0,n)
}
```

Is this ok, or should I just get over it?

Next, I'm going to write a `.right()`, a `.mid()`, a `.val()` and a `.int()`.

Comment: I wouldn't do it, extending builtin objects is an anti-pattern IMO.

Comment: @elclanrs that could be a fine answer if you also propose an alternative with sample code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending native objects is bad practice.

- When you're expecting nothing, then something shows up. That's natural behavior of prototypes.
- Forwards compatibility. The same reason why `Object.keys(someObjectInstance)` is designed that way instead of `someObjectInstance.keys()` - because some implementations may already have used `keys` as a property. So what if ECMAScript 9 wants to use `left()` and `right()` for some string operation, your app will break.

For alternatives:

- You can create your own functions in a separate namespace, that looks like the native functions. For instance, the native `forEach` looks like `array.forEach(fn)`. Underscore writes it differently with `_.forEach(array,fn)`.
- You can extend native objects. Mileage may vary on this one as some (not sure which, but most) native objects are not subclassable.
- You could create "wrapper objects" that just wrap the object into another object, who has methods that operate on the wrapped object. A good example is jQuery which wraps an array of stuff in a "jQuery object" which hosts a myriad of DOM manipulation methods that operate on that set.
- Create a custom object that doesn't necessarily extend/inherit/wrap anything. Something like `var string = new CustomString('hello world')`.